# RadioButton application-level Style not working with ControlTemplate on iOS in MAUI

Tags: xaml, radio-button, maui, controltemplate

I'm using a ControlTemplate to define the look of my RadioButtons on a page. When I define the ControlTemplate and assign it as a Style to TargetType RadioButton in ContentPage.Resources the RadioButton behaves as expected on the ContentPage. If I move the ControlTemplate and the assignment of it as a Style to TargetType RadioButton in Styles.xaml as an Application level resource, the RadioButtons look as described in the ControlTemplate on iOS and Android but they do not respond to any clicks on iOS. They work as I expect on Android.

To reproduce the issue, I used the sample code provide in the RadioButton MAUI documentation. Here is my XAML with the ControlTemplate defined as a ContentPage level resource that works on both iOS and Android.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Splash.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
            <Border Stroke="#F3F2F1"
                    StrokeThickness="2"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10"
                    BackgroundColor="#F3F2F1"
                    HeightRequest="90"
                    WidthRequest="90"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="Start">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                            Value="#FF3300" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="check"
                                            Property="Opacity"
                                            Value="1" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                            Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="check"
                                            Property="Opacity"
                                            Value="0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid Margin="4"
                      WidthRequest="90">
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,4,0"
                          WidthRequest="18"
                          HeightRequest="18"
                          HorizontalOptions="End"
                          VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Blue"
                                 Fill="White"
                                 WidthRequest="16"
                                 HeightRequest="16"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Ellipse x:Name="check"
                                 Fill="Blue"
                                 WidthRequest="8"
                                 HeightRequest="8"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Label Text="What's your favorite animal?" />
                <RadioButton Content="Cat" />
                <RadioButton Content="Dog" />
                <RadioButton Content="Elephant" />
                <RadioButton Content="Monkey"
                             IsChecked="true" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

When I remove the ControlTemplate and Style assignment as a ContentPage resource and move it to Styles.xaml, this is what it looks like in Styles.xaml:

```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
        <Border Stroke="#F3F2F1"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10"
                BackgroundColor="#F3F2F1"
                HeightRequest="90"
                WidthRequest="90"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                VerticalOptions="Start">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                        Value="#FF3300" />
                                <Setter TargetName="check"
                                        Property="Opacity"
                                        Value="1" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                        Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="check"
                                        Property="Opacity"
                                        Value="0" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid Margin="4"
                    WidthRequest="90">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,4,0"
                        WidthRequest="18"
                        HeightRequest="18"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Blue"
                                Fill="White"
                                WidthRequest="16"
                                HeightRequest="16"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Ellipse x:Name="check"
                                Fill="Blue"
                                WidthRequest="8"
                                HeightRequest="8"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="44"/>
        <Setter Property="MinimumWidthRequest" Value="44"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Here is a screenshot of how the RadioButtons look on an iPhone emulator which is the same as how they look on an Android emulator with only minor differences.

[image]

I tried defining the ControlTemplate in a separate ResourceDictionary from Styles.xaml and got the same result. I'm considering trying to create a custom RadioButton control as a workaround.

Any thoughts on why this might not be working on iOS other than it being a bug? Any thoughts on a workaround to assign a RadioButton ControlTemplate to a RadioButton Style at the Application level?

Comment: I can reproduce. You may raise an issue on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues)

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT issue is raised (like a year or so ago?). The bigger problem is with android however. The only solution that works for both mobile platforms (at the same time) is to manually control the state of the radio buttons. Bindings with parameters do help.

Comment: About your statement: "They work as I expect on Android". Just try to do something more complex with them, and you will see how "magically" they will stop responding to your clicks. Here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8325 Here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6938 and one million more, just search.

Comment: @H.A.H. Thanks for response. I test it on iOS. and i found the CheckedChanged event for Radiobutton is not fired when put op's ControlTemplate in App.xaml or Style.xaml, but in Android it works. It only works in a page's resource for iOS. If you have solution, you can post an answer below which helps others with same issues.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I cannot make the radio buttons to work. All we can do is play the waiting game. Right now I am manually handling IsChecked. This is not a solution. This is plain and simple stupid.

Comment: I saw these reported issued too. They certainly need to be addressed but this seems different given that my ControlTemplate works find on Android.

Comment: Submitted as dotnet/maui bug report #14949.

Comment: Have you tried using a custom control for radiobutton and with some bindings for IsChecked like H.A.H said?

Comment: No. I didn’t try that. For now, I’m sticking with a ControlTemplate individual pages.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We can follow the thread on Github.